# Intuition/interpretation for the value of the spectral density calculated at the zero frequency

Tags: time-series, intuition, central-limit-theorem, moving-average, spectral-analysis

Is there any easy way to think about the value of the spectral density at the zero frequency? How do people interpret it usually?

I have been studying some time series on my own and encountered a CLT for dependent data (covariance stationary and ergodic processes). The sufficient conditions of that CLT fail if that value of the spectral density is 0. Apparently, it can happen even in  seemingly nice cases such as the following MA(1): 
$$X_t=\varepsilon_t-\varepsilon_{t-1}, \quad \varepsilon \sim w.n. (0, \sigma^2).$$